# Unable to get value for all property of item attachment using EWS Managed API

Tags: exchange-server, exchangewebservices

Following property of item attachment did not populate using below statement

- Content Type
- Content location

I wrote below code to get information about exchange item attachment

```
Appointment app =Item.Bind(<<ExchangeService Object>>,<<ItemId>>, new PropertySet(ItemSchema.Attachment)) as Appointment;
```

I could get all other properties information like Name, Size of file but value for properties mention above does not get populated.

Answer (score 0):

After you do the `Bind()` to the attachment, you also need to do a `Load()` to get all the attachment information. Check out this article on MSDN for more information:

[Getting attachments by using the EWS Managed API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd633665%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx)

I hope this helps. If this does resolve your problem, please mark the post as answered.

Thanks,

--- Bob ---